# Implement a simple title-tag check

Tags: feature-request, tags, title

I notice a lot of questions like this:

## C# My Question

Details... Details...

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

Can't a simple check be done that says "you cannot start a question title with the name of a language tag" or something like that? It would save a lot of editing and would pretty much be a `BeginsWith` call.